# Cannot access methods of closed over jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have a function like so:

```
var eatLunch = (function () {
    var sandwiches = [$("#sand1"), $("#sand2")];

    return function (eaten) {
        for (var i = 0, len = eaten.length; i < len; i++) {
            sandwiches[i].attr("class", "eaten-by " + eaten[i].by)
        }
    };
}());

eatLunch([
    {
        result: "good",
        by: "Adam"
    },
    {
        result: "meh",
        by: "Adam"
    }
]);
```

The intention is to cache the dom elements #sand1 and #sand2 in a closure to reduce the number of dom touches this function has to make. Without closure, the elements have to be assigned to variables every time I call the function.

However, the attr method does not seem to work. Upon further inspection, sandwiches[i] is defined, and it has the attr method. The function does not throw an error, it just keeps looping, but the dom elements do not get updated.

If I move sandwiches into the local scope, it works perfectly, but this is more expensive. See below:

```
var eatLunch = function (eaten) {
    var sandwiches = [$("sand1"), $("sand2")];

    for (var i = 0, len = eaten.length; i < len; i++) {
        sandwiches[i].attr("class", "eaten-by " + eaten[i].by)
    }
};

eatLunch([
    {
        result: "good",
        by: "Adam"
    },
    {
        result: "meh",
        by: "Adam"
    }
]);
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running your code before the DOM is loaded.

Move it to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I think this was it. The function is defined before those elements are present, as the page content is loaded in through ajax.

Comment: That did it. I refactored my code to define the variables in the closure, but not assign them. Then every time the eatLunch gets called I check if sandwiches.length is 0. If so, I assign the dom elements to sandwiches. That way I only pay for the dom touches the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

`var i = 0, var len = eaten.length;`

Don't use `var` in the second one. Write:

`var i = 0, len = eaten.length;`

You also need to change `eaten.by` to `eaten[i].by`

Minor errors are a pain to find.

[Live Fixed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/puFMR/10/)

Comment: This doesn't explain why his second example works.  I wonder if this is really his real code.

Comment: @Slaks [I tried his second example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/puFMR/11/), it's broken :\

Comment: This is just an illustrative example. This is a simplified version. The errors you mentioned were typos in the example. I have updated them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Adam then we need actual code. As you can see your example works in my fiddle. Your bug is more complex then what you have supplied us.